# Arping to google.com fails

Tags: ping, arp

I am trying to follow the instructions here, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netconsole to set up netconsole in ubuntu machine.

This uses, `arping` command which is non-responsive when i run it in my machine.

To understand it better, i ran,

```
arping -I wlan0 google.com -f
```

But it shows,

```
Sent 84 probes (84 broadcast(s))
Received 0 response(s)
```

When i do `ping google.com`, it sends and receives packets with no hassles.

Does public facing servers disable arp queries?

How can i configure remote machines to respond for arping-queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a computer connected to `google.com` (it's `216.58.220.206` from my site) in 1 hop?

ARP packets are sent as Ethernet broadcast in the local network segment, so you can use `arping` for probing neighbour hosts in the same network.  Instead of `google.com`, try it with your default gateway address for `wlan0` subnet.

Comment: `google.com` is that address from your site *now*; it'll probably change in a few minutes when the TTL expires and you get a new response from the DNS server, chosen to distribute load over many machines. And it's different around the world, to direct traffic to (relatively) nearby machines. But that does not alter your point: *none* of these machines is on the OP's LAN, so even if he could somehow learn the MAC address of one of them he couldn't send anything to it. In contrast `ping` uses IP which is routed across networks (hence the name Internet Protocol).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yeah I know the nature of geometrically distributed services.  Thanks for your further explanation on that.